# How to add indexOf in array and how to add elements to an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I keep getting 0 as my answer when I am supposed to get 0,3,6,9. also How do you add the indexof an array to the array? not sure if I did it properly.

```
/**
         * This returns an int array containing a multiplication table. Your method
         * should start by allocating an array whose length is {@code numEntries} (e.g.,
         * the second parameter). You should then set the value of each entry in the
         * array equal to {@code constant} (e.g., the first parameter) times the index
         * of that entry.<br/>
         * Precondition: numEntries MUST BE 0 or larger. (PRECONDITIONS SPECIFY
         * RESPONSIBILITIES ON A METHOD'S CALLER; YOU SHOULD ASSUME THIS IS TRUE.)
         *
         * @param constant
         *            Value whose multiplication table is to be calculated.
         * @param numEntries
         *            Length of the array to be returned
         * @return Array of the appropriate length containing the multiplication table
         *         for {@code constant}.
         */
        public static int[] generateTable(int constant, int numEntries) {
            int arr[];
            arr=new int[numEntries];
            int i;
            int ans;
            for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                ans=(arr[i])*constant;
                System.out.println(ans);
                arr[i]=ans;

            }
            System.out.println(arr);
            return arr;


        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateTable(3,4);
    }
```

Comment: change ans=(arr[i])*constant to ans=i*constant

Answer (score 2):

You want `ans = i * constant;`. But, I would eliminate `ans`. I would also only print in the caller. Like,

```
public static int[] generateTable(int constant, int numEntries) {
    int[] arr = new int[numEntries];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i * constant;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateTable(3, 4)));
}
```

Of course, in Java 8+, you could also use a lambda to do it. Like,

```
public static int[] generateTable(int constant, int numEntries) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numEntries).map(i -> i * constant).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to start with an initial value (you don't have assigned anything to arr[0], when you first use it). Then you have to assign the result of your calculation to a different index than the one, where you got it from.
I would recommend setting arr[0]=const before the loop, let the loop run till i < arr.length-1 and inside the loop assign ans to arr[i+1].

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't initialized/set any values for your array. You just created an array of size 'numEntries' and each entry in that array is 0 ([0,0,0,0]). Change this ans=(arr[i])*constant to ans=i*constant

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens in your code , when you give the number of entries as 4 it creates an array of length of 4 with each holding 0 as it's value. This is what it(array) look likes initially when you call  `arr=new int[numEntries];`

[image]

```
  ans=(arr[i])*constant;
```

So when you execute the above line it will always gives you 0 because the initial values are 0 even though you multiply with the constant.

```
   arr[i]=ans;
```

As a result when you execute the above line the ans(which is always 0) will be assigned to the element of that index resulting the output of

> I keep getting 0 as my answer

**Solution**

What you need to do is change the

ans=(arr[i])*constant;

to

```
ans=i*constant;
```

will give you the result

> 0,3,6,9

The whole code should be something like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateTable(3,4);
}


public static int[] generateTable(int constant, int numEntries) {
        int arr[];
        arr=new int[numEntries];
        int i;
        int ans;
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            ans=i*constant;
            System.out.println(ans);
            arr[i]=ans;

        }
        System.out.println(arr);
        return arr;
}
```

Note: There can be different ways in which you can gain the same output(0,3,6,9...).